# Sql server Cursor vs While Loop performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I have used Sql server Cursor.
i have insert 10K record in db and insert multiple table in related some data but  take some time
so any suggestion for how to increase some speed in sql server.
 Which loop base in sql server ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Old rule since 20 years: DO NOT USE CURSORS. Their performance is atrocious and you loose 90% of what SQL Server does to queries for performance on top of that. Start taking your code and write SET based SQL, not procedural loops.

Answer (score 1):

While loop is always better than cursor which provide more control, you can go with combination of Common table expression

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/